# Firefox cannot print content of large divs

Tags: html, firefox

Open the following HTML in Firefox

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 1000px; height: 4000px;">
            <div style="margin-left: 500px; margin-top: 2000px; position: absolute;">Caption </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Click Print -> Preview.

You expected to see word **Caption** on the second page (in portrait mode) but all pages are empty.

Comment: if you give your parent div `position:relative` it should work.

Comment: @Murtaza this did not help as well. Tested in Firefox 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `position:absolute`.  Your element has no positioned ancestors, so its containing block is the initial containing block, per http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details .  In print CSS the initial containing block is the area of the first page, per http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-area

So you're asking for the element to be positioned on the first page of the document, 2000px from the top of the page.  Which happens to be off the bottom of the page, of course.  There's nothing there saying that this generates any more pages...

Comment: but `position:relative` does not help as well.

Comment: Hmm.  That's really odd. Please file a bug?

Comment: I tried
`<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 1000px; height: 4000px;">
            <div style="margin-left: 500px; margin-top: 2000px; position: relative;">Caption </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`
and
`<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 1000px; height: 4000px; position: relative;">
            <div style="margin-left: 500px; margin-top: 2000px; position: relative;">Caption </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`

nothing helped. Tested on FireFox 10.

I raised a bug on bugzilla:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=722968

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

Of course, you could just write a CSS for print media:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Hence, when you print, the height property can be specified to something far less than 4000px.

Then again, why do you need such a large height?

Comment: I am developing an application where user can design his own custom form. This form can be big. It's up to user. Now I wanted to write print.css and encountered the issue.